What is reification in philosophy of science and why is it a fallacy?
This is related to what someone said as I was coming across topics on this site and looking through stuff. Here is the remark:

to understand why natural kinds are constructed, why abstract objects don't exist, and how our senses, perception, and linguistic abilities are highly entwined at the level of intuition to explain why many ontological commitments to abstracta are category mistakes.

I don't really know what all that is supposed to mean, even after googling all the terms. The last part especially about ontological commitments and after that it mentioned Reification.
Ummm...can someone translate this for me? I can't make sense of what it's saying, or even what the fallacy itself means. What exactly is reification in the philosophy of science and why is it a fallacy?

I've tweaked the Q a little bit and taken a shot at answering it. Feel free to roll back.

Reification=to transform a fiction into something real.

State, justice, taxes, bank accounts: examples of real abstraction.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I don’t get your meaning. It’s fiction but we live our lives by them right? Wouldn’t science be the same thing too along with logic if all that stuff isn’t real? I don’t get it.

@BoltStorm Yes, we can live our lives according to fictions. That means in one sense fictions are real! But you wouldn't go to Tokyo to see a real Godzilla, would you. Some philosophers think that scientists are just another group of story tellers, to over simply.

@JD That sorta reminds me of Terry Pratchet as Death saying “humans need fantasy to be human, to be the place where the falling angel meets the rising ape”. And also “you need to believe in things that aren’t true, how else can they become”? But wouldn’t they be right about the scientists thought because science is telling a story based on data and what’s happening. It’s our best guess of what it all means and it can be wrong.

A kid plowing a field in 1920 came up with the idea of raster scan television. Was the idea real? Does television exist, or just big hunks of plastic? Ask someone who solved a crime using video evidence.

@ScottRowe Yes.

Science traditionally is concerned with determining what is real or not. Since natural philosophy has grown into post-modern science, the position of most scientists about what is real is called scientific realism. From WP:

Scientific realism is the view that the universe described by science is real regardless of how it may be interpreted. A believer of scientific realism takes the universe as described by science to be true (or approximately true), because of their assertion that science can be used to find the truth (or approximate truth) about both the physical and metaphysical in the Universe.

For instance, scientists claim horses are real, and unicorns are not. The question of which entities are real and exist is studied in philosophy in ontology. A scientific ontology contains things scientists consider real and exist. Biologists, for instance, study biological organisms like horses, flies, and monkeys. They reject leprechauns, unicorns, and pegasi.
But somethings scientists use everyday have a questionable material status. For instance, are numbers real? What about God? Are aliens visiting us? Here, the discussions can get heated among different people who call themselves scientists. Some scientists say numbers are real, but others insist they are fiction. Some scientists believe God exists, and others are atheists. Most scientists call aliens fictions and consider ufologists pseudoscientists, but some ufologists have strong scientific credentials and claim the government is conspiring to keep the existence of aliens secret.
Whatever you believe is real and exists, you are ontologically committed to in your language (even if you believe an ontological primitive is a fiction). For instance, in computer science, one commits to software. Is software real? Does it exist physically? Some say it is an abstraction layer of hardware and doesn't actually exist.
When scientists start arguing over what is real and what is not, and what exists and what is not, they often accuse each other of committing category mistakes or the reification fallacy. A category error is when you claim that something like love is the same as apples, oranges, and bananas. One is a psychological experience, and the other are physical fruits. The reification fallacy is the accusation that a scientist is reasoning about something abstract as if it were real. For instance, to reason about numbers like molecules might lead to some strange arguments, because numbers arguably do not have a physical existence.
So, the reification fallacy is a fallacy, because it meets the definition of a fallacy. A fallacy is a persuasive argument that often relies on irrelevant claims, has no logical grounds, or is somehow emotional but otherwise logically wrong. And for scientists, deciding how to deal with abstracta like numbers, feelings, and untestable subjects like strings (of string theory), can cause a lot of debate with accusations other scientists are thinking irrationally and illogically. This is because scientists tend to emphasize the value of  empirical evidence and abstract lack concrete existence.

+1 It seems that reification is a broad term. False analogies and anthropomorphism fall under this term as well.

@IdiosyncraticSoul Yeah, there are no limits to what fictional thing of this sort or that can be considered real, it seems. Part of the whole stress caused by intuitional dualism. It's hard to agree too, if one thinker is a reductive physicalist, and another is non-physical property dualist, because the basic categories of 'physical' and 'mental' are themselves in dispute I guess. It all goes on the topic of appearance and actuality, I suppose.

Don't tell people software doesn't exist, they'll stop paying me to make it, using money that doesn't exist, so I can buy other things that don't exist, like the mortgage on my house. ('mort-gage' originally meant "death pledge", because they didn't expect anyone to live long enough to pay it off, so the lender was guaranteed to get their property back when the man died, throwing his family out on the street.)

@ScottRowe Ah, laissez-fair capitalism at its finest! As an absurdist, I find it delightful that people can go 40 years before they realize the system really is just a series of sleights of hand to move wealth upward. :D But, it beats Venezuelan-style socialism or North Korean central planning, so until I learn enough Norwegian, I'm in the same boat as you.

@JD I’m not sure I understand. I think software is real because it’s what makes a computer a computer. Without software it’s just a hunk of metal, or plastic or whatever. Also this whole “exist” and “real” thing is kinda confusing. If love is psychological then does that mean it’s not real and I’m not feeling it if it doesn’t exist physically? What does it mean for abstract objects to not exist? I’m more lost than before. What does the quote I mentioned even mean? I don’t understand.

@BoltStorm You can't weigh software. It has no mass. It has no length (or what Descartes would call extension). You can't taste it or touch it or see it directly. If you buy a CD (I think they still sell them), then what you are touching is the CD, the medium, and not the software itself. Numbers have no mass. Algorithms have no mass. When you add software to a computer, it doesn't really get heavier the way adding rocks to a truck happens. Software is abstract, not concrete. It is information, not a device. It pertains the the mental, and not to the material...

And the words "exist" and "real" are not just confusing to you, but lie at the center of a lot of arguments in philosophy! So take heart, they confuse just about all who try to explain them.

@JD But without it you don’t have a computer. Even graphics cards and other hardware need drivers to function. Otherwise they’re just expensive paperweights. That doesn’t sound abstract, that seems pretty concrete. Maybe for something to exist it doesn’t have to be material. I read the problem with labeling things as material is we can’t prove it. That’s sorta the hard problem of solipsism. Others say nothing exists, just our concepts of things (Buddhism I think). So I guess some would say it’s all mental and not material or real.

@JD Well I got the quote there from an answer of yours about anti-realism, of which I couldn’t make heads or tails of and it just left me confused.

@BoltStorm I think a good question is whether we are able to see beyond our concepts or not. I think this relates to the Buddhist idea. We see our concepts, but they exist only in our minds. The universe doesn't care about them.

@ScottRowe Well even seeing beyond a concept is a concept, so no. Also recent research into neuroscience suggests that consciousness is conceptual, or the brain's theory about itself. I guess depending on your definition of the universe it does care about them.

@BoltStorm if there is a definition of the universe that doesn't care about concepts, then it is kind of like a bucket with a hole: concepts don't hold water. Concepts fail, the universe goes on.

@ScottRowe Yes and no, because the universe is a concept we use to refer to “this”. The concepts do hold water because we technically are the universe (in a manner of speaking) so the universe would by definition care about concepts. I guess it would also depend on your stance on solipsism.

@BoltStorm If you go down that path, that we are the universe, then you are in idealism which is the idea that are thinking is real, and the material world is not. Solipsism is just an extreme version of that.

@JD Well no, there is a materialistic view of that since we are "made of star stuff" as Carl Sagan put it. We are made of the same thing everything else is made out of so it's not really a stretch to say we and everything else are the universe. Also Idealism doesn't necessarily mean that our thinking is real but that mind is primary, though they usually refer to a God mind there not really our own. Though you have to admit the hard problem of solipsism is a hard problem for a reason. It's why reification in my view might not really be a fallacy, especially since all we know are concepts.

Reification is a Latin composite word "res"+"facere" and essentially means "thing"-"ify". So you're turning an idea or concept into a concrete physical object.
Probably something like this:

In case you can't see it, it's the famous picture of a pipe with the French subscript "This is not a pipe". Which is ironic, as if you're asked to picture a pipe there's a huge chance it might look something like that, though at the same time the artist is correct in saying that if you'd try to stuff it (with tobacco), it wouldn't work, so if he told you "this is a pipe", he'd have been lying to you.
Which also illustrates the problem with that, namely that while the picture shares a lot of features with a real pipe, making people scream out "but that IS a pipe", it's also not actually a pipe and so some analogies don't actually work.

to understand why natural kinds are constructed, why abstract objects don't exist, and how our senses, perception, and linguistic abilities are highly entwined at the level of intuition to explain why many ontological commitments to abstracta are category mistakes.

Now obviously that is an incomplete sentence, both grammatically and logically... So not sure what that tried to say. Though with regards to reification and thought, ... well yeah we tend to think a lot in terms of physical objects. Like we love grouping features, behaviors and correlated events into one "thing" and after we've done that we apply a language of physical objects to them. Like "the wind blows" ascribes some active agency and personhood to "the wind". However there is no entity of "wind" and "it" certainly doesn't actively blow or anything. It's merely the fluctuation of air molecules due to reactions to changes in the thermodynamic situation. So rather passive interaction of relatively unconnected parts.
So calling it "wind" is a "construct" (= "heap together") so a reification. Though while fallacious it's often enough how we think. But also our concept of knowledge often around revolves around turning these shapeless abstracts into concrete objects that we "get", that we (can) grasp and whatnot. So while many of these things aren't actually real, but things that we construct, that intuition might nonetheless be the basis of our intuition and testing those analogies that is what we utilize to test those models.

The more I read it the less I’m convinced it’s an actual fallacy because we do name these things to be better able to talk about them. To call the wind the fluctuations of air molecules is technically correct but also wrong. There is an “entity” called wind and we measure the speed of it to determine how strong to build structures and whether they can resist such forces. So in a sense I would say you’re wrong about this entity of wind and whether it blows. I also think you’re not accurate in that the statement is assigning agency or personhood. It’s just how people refer to a force.

Also by that measure all of science is reification because we have concepts of the things we measure, including molecules

@BoltStorm The problem is that this is having it kinda backwards, because the speed is not the property of the entity that is the wind, the speed IS what we call the wind. Which even puts us in trouble visualizing wind, because a) it's invisible and b) it's a thing that causes itself or is itself!? Like popular depictions of wind are just motion blur lines and clouds making a blowing face. Where the further is more correct than the latter, but neither is capturing the actual thing. Also you say it's easier to talk about "it", but what is it you're actually talking about?

@BoltStorm Like the way we talk about it assigns an entity to an event, we talk of it in active terms implying that we're talking about an entity or further an agent, that is capable of actively doing something. Sure that's how our language works because physical objects and the interactions with them are the most "objective" we can get so basing our languages on that is pretty straight forward, but this comes to limits with regards to trying to fit abstract ideas into that category because they don't necessarily fit and analogies might not work.

@BoltStorm Also yes science does a lot of reification, pretty much all of particle physics is, "oh there's a localized force? Let's call it a particle!". In terms of light we even got into the struggle that light is both a wave-entity and a particle-entity and that there are situations where it's more wavy or more particly. Also with regards to deductive logic science is fallacious as building a generalized theory from observation is a fallacy. That is it's not a certainty, but comes with margins of errors. Which is the case for all of science, yet it's still pretty successful.

Well we are talking about an entity because that’s what wind is, the movement of particles. But in a weird way it is both the speed and the “entity” becauee speed is a property of something and not the thing itself. So to say the speed is what we call the wind isn’t entirely accurate. Also you know what it is that we’re talking about so why ask? This is why I wonder if reification is a valid fallacy to call upon.

The way we talk about it doesn’t assign an entity to an event. People don’t literally mean the wind isn’t conscious so much as it is a force that changes. Kinda like the ocean. But even if they do so what? I haven’t really seen any limits to that language and people know what is meant by “the wind is howling” or “the sea is angry”. You haven’t really given any indication of the limits of this or how something doesn’t fit. The same issue that I had with the quote I put up there.

Well I don’t know if localized force is a particle. They do exist. But what I meant is that everything we know is conceptual, an idea we have of something. So if you want to invoke reification as a fallacy you’d have to do it to all human knowledge, everything we do. I might grant that building a body of knowledge on observation is a fallacy but at the same time I wouldn’t. Because observation is all you have, so if you want to deride that then you have nothing. Even logic and reason are rooted in it as well.

"...to understand why natural kinds are constructed, why abstract objects don't exist, and how our senses, perception, and linguistic abilities are highly entwined at the level of intuition to explain why many ontological commitments to abstracta are category mistakes."
"In philosophy and science, reification is a fallacy that occurs when an abstract idea is treated as if it were a concrete entity."

"...to understand why natural kinds are constructed, why abstract objects don't exist.."
What was the statement prior to the quote beginning? You can argue that abstract objects certainly exist. Human beings are abstract creatures. Every single thing in life is abstract when you look into it with sufficient interest.

"... how our senses, perception, and linguistic abilities are highly entwined at the level of intuition to explain why many ontological commitments to abstracta..."
Our physical and even metaphysical faculties have developed over time to satisfy our desire to understand existential curiosities.

"... category mistakes."
I'm not sure what they mean by that. Maybe it would make more sense within the proper context.



It's part of this answer I found from (I guess the mod?) but I couldn't really understand it: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/106478/88743

They have to be referring to the way we conceptualize certain aspects of life being incorrectly compartmentalized.  But I'm not sure in exactly what way they mean.

Lost sight of the original question though.

I’m not sure either. I googled the terms in the answer but rather than being facts they’re more like philosophical stances. The only thing that was right was logical positivism failing, but I don’t really get what that means. When I googled the science used to back it the research behind it was shaky at best. Embodied cognition is far from settled and was considered pseudoscience. Predictive coding is iffy because we can’t test it and the link cites Lisa Barrett whose research is iffy because some studies she used argued against her main point. At my glance it seems biased.

Also when I checked the comments I didn’t really see an explanation but just quoting a bunch of topics I didn’t understand and terms as well. I don’t think if someone read 50 books on the subject they should be able to explain things a bit better.
